# Why jslint is not working with npm package

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, jslint, jshint

I installed :

`npm i jslint`

`jslint@0.12.1 updated 1 package and audited 6594 packages in 5.791s found 53 vulnerabilities (15 low, 16 moderate, 22 high)`

I have made some configurations :
`./node_modules/.bin/jslint --init`

then :
`./node_modul.es/.bin/jslint gulpfile.js --fix`

I have got suggestions but it is not fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways of installing npm packages.

Locally and globally.

You've installed the package locally but are trying to run a global command.

To install the package globally you could run the following command

```
npm i -g jslint
```

Alternatively, since you don't have global permissions you could install it locally and add an npm script to the package.json file in your project:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "jslint gulpfile.js"
}
```

And run it with

```
npm run lint
```

Comment: I don't have permission to install it globally. I need to run in local itself. But cannot able to run.

Comment: Answer edited with solution in case of no global permissions

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have permissions to install globally, and you use npm version 5.2+, you can use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx).

It downloads the package and executes it locally.

Usage:

`npx jslint --init`

JSlint doesn't seem to have a --fix option, so your second command wouldn't work anyway. Consider using [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) which has auto fix feature

Comment: Yes. It is the requirement that these scripts should run in all the browsers. IE10 and greater. Yes ESlint is a good option. But it will show suggestions ES6 also. That I don't want to implement.

Comment: Is there is a method where I will use ESlint and filter all ES6 concepts. May be in the settings in the JSON file.

Comment: You can set the env key in .eslintrc.json. `{env:{es6:false}}`

Comment: I setted {env:{es6:false}} but still it is showing es6 suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you can add `/*eslint-env es6:false*/` to your codes